# Unable to Call Oracle Stored Procedure from Sqoop

Tags: oracle, hadoop, stored-procedures, sqoop

I want to call an Oracle stored procedure from Sqoop but I'm getting an error. I have to call a function of stored procedure and need to pass the parameter.

```
$: sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1512/db --username userA --password password --call Oracle_Schema.pkg_table_maintenance.sf_drop_index('TBL_A_%','Group_id')

-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

$: sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1512/db --username userA --password password --call "Oracle_Schema.pkg_table_maintenance.sf_drop_index('TBL_A_%','Group_id')"

Warning: /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.7-1.cdh5.4.7.p1246.1021/bin/../lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
17/11/27 10:31:31 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.5-cdh5.4.7
17/11/27 10:31:32 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
17/11/27 10:31:32 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing arguments for import:
17/11/27 10:31:32 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --call
17/11/27 10:31:32 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: Oracle_Schema.pkg_table_maintenance.sf_drop_index('TBL_A_%','Group_id')
```

Can someone please help!

Comment: seems trivial from the information : `Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation`

Answer (score 1):

Sqoop allows you to call a sql procedure only when you are exporting, not when you import.

Answer (score 0):

If you stored procedure does some kind of select to import through sqoop-import that will not work, sqoop import doesn't have that flexibility.

But if your stored procedure is doing some kind of clean-up operation you can use the below sqoop eval utility

```
sqoop eval --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1512/db --username userA --password password --query "EXECUTE Oracle_Schema.pkg_table_maintenance.sf_drop_index('TBL_A_%','Group_id')"
```

--query "will execute the query as if you are running in oracle database, you can use the same SQL syntax that you will use from oracle client application/command line"

Answer (score 0):

you can execute a stored procedure in Sqoop by using the Sql*plus method to execute a stored procedure: `BEGIN STORED_PROCEDURE; END;`

```
sqoop eval -Dmapred.job.queue.name=root.test.test-mis \
 --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@SERVER.NAME:PORT:INSTANCE --password **** \
 --username MYSCHEMA --query "BEGIN MYSCHEMA.TEST_STORED_PROCEDURE_NAME; END;"
```